# Flask wtf form AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'POST'

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I just started coding with Flask and I want to set up CSRF on a small form in my application. I am following this https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html for session based implementation. I looked around the web for a while for a solution to a similar problem but I had no success, apologies if this is a duplicate question.

**Problem with this code:**
When I run it in the virtual environment I get `AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'POST'` -

**Goal:** implement csrf on wtform instance

**Environment**: wtf version 2.02, flask 0.10, venv with python 2.7

**fci_form.py**

```
from flask import session, request
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import TextField, validators, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Required, Length
from wtforms.csrf.session import SessionCSRF
from datetime import timedelta
import config # my config file

# create super class

class MyForm(Form):
    class Meta:
        csrf = True
        csrf_class = SessionCSRF
        csrf_secret = config.secret_key
        csrf_time_limit = timedelta(minutes=20)

        @property
            def csrf_context(self):
                return request.session


# create a class for the form
class postcodeInput(MyForm):
    postcode = TextField('postcode',[validators.Required(message=(u"Where is your postcode?")),validators.Length(min=2, max=10)])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

**views.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, __version__, url_for, session, abort, flash, redirect
# importing the class called postcode_input
from fci_form import postcodeInput
import config
import fciUtils

#pdb.set_trace()
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

# Views of the app

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/fci', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def fci_form():
    error = None
    form = postcodeInput(request.POST, meta={'csrf_context': request.session})
    if form.validate_on_submit():
            # handle user input
            postcode = request.form['postcode']
            # calculate fci
            result = fciUtils.fciReturn(postcode)
            return render_template('fci_form.html',form = form, result = result)
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('fci_form.html', form = form)
    else:
        error = 'Enter a valid postcode'
        return render_template('fci_form.html', form=form, error=error)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = config.secret_key
    app.run(threaded=True)
```

The template is **fci_form.html** in the/templates folder

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block form %}
<section>
    <header><h1>...</h1><br></header>
    <form action="{{ url_for('fci_form')}}" method='POST'>
        <p>Enter your London postcode:</p>
        <section>
            {% if error %}
            <p class="error"><strong>Error: </strong>{{error}}</p>
            {% endif %}
            {{form.csrf_token}}
            {{form.postcode}}
            {{form.submit(class_="pure-button")}}   
        </section>
    </form> 
</section> 

{% endblock %}

{% block result %}

    <section>
        <h4>{{result}}</h4> 
    </section>

{% endblock %}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

From the [github README](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/#wtforms) for the WTForms project:

> WTForms is a flexible forms validation and rendering library for
>   Python web development. **It is framework agnostic** and can work with
>   whatever web framework and template engine you choose.

..emphasis mine. Framework agnostic means that this isn't just a library for Flask and that examples such as these (from https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html#using-csrf):

```py
def view():
    form = UserForm(request.POST)
    if request.POST and form.validate():
        pass # Form is valid and CSRF succeeded

    return render('user.html', form=form)
```

... aren't necessarily a working pattern in *any* web framework, rather just a general illustration to exhibit how the library works.

That example transposed to a Flask specific example might look something like this:

```py
@app.route('/submit', methods=("GET", "POST"))
def submit():
    form = UserForm(request.form)
    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
        pass  # Form is valid and CSRF succeeded
    return render_template('submit.html', form=form)
```

The README goes on to say:

> There are various community libraries that provide closer integration with
>   popular frameworks.

One such example is [Flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), and the 'hello world' for their library around WTForms looks like this:

```py
@app.route('/submit', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def submit():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect('/success')
    return render_template('submit.html', form=form)
```

Notice that `request.form` doesn't have to be passed to the `MyForm` constructor as it did in the vanilla WTForms example (`UserForm(request.form)`), and that there is a method available on the forms called `validate_on_submit()` which both tests that the request is a `POST` request and also that the submitted form content passes validation.

Along with easier handling of passing `POST` data through to forms, and validation, `Flask-WTF` also simplifies CSRF token management, which can be read about [here](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html).